# PhpStorm how to place closing brace on the next line for namespase imports?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

If i use "Optimize Imports" anв namespaces was grouped, then closing brace places on the same line as the last namespace. What do I do to place the closing brace on the next line?

For example

```
use app\models\{
    User,
    Settings,
    Site
}
```

At the moment I get this:

```
use app\models\{
    User,
    Settings,
    Site}
```

`Wrapping and Braces` → `Braces Placement` → `Other` → `Next line` is not suitable, because it's only for methods, functions and classes

Comment: Just tried that with the default settings (apart from "Group 'use': Wrap Always") and the closing brace position did not change. Does it happen on default settings too in your case?

Comment: @duck_in_hat unfortunately, yes))   And all manipulations with "wrapping & braces" affects only to code in methods/functions and classes, not to the namespaces imports.